# Upon boot resolv.conf is empty, but then eventually is populated; why?

Tags: networking, 17.10, amazon-ec2, resolv.conf, cloud-init

I have a few 17.10 instances running in Amazon EC2 on a VPC. When I freshly reboot a server (unsure if it happens on a cold boot, I have not tested), the `/etc/resolv.conf` file shows as empty:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
```

Name resolution fails as expected, for example when connecting to a server with a static IP on the private subnet via its internal DNS name:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname example: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Now if I wait for some period of time, suddenly the proper values appear in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search subdomain.example.com
```

The `systemd-resolve --status` command reports the same. The `/etc/resolv.conf` file is also properly set if I manually force a `dhclient` renew, and I know that these values are coming from the EC2 DHCP server.

So the question is: What part of my configuration is missing that prevents this from happening immediately upon boot?

Adding these values directly to something like `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` would work but then I'm hard-coding something that should arrive via DHCP, I believe. I've looked in `/etc/netplan` as well (`ifupdown` is not being used) and this seems to come from the cloud init stuff, so I wonder if maybe I am missing something in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` or similar?

Comment: I found some similar problems that were resolved by replacing the symbolic link to `/etc/resolv.conf` with `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, but this is actually the same as just removing `resolvconf` entirely, for example `apt-get purge resolvconf`. These do "fix" the problem, but I am still curious to see how to make it work _with_ `resolvconf` running as it always had in the past.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm encountering something similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296576/etc-resolv-conf-not-populated-on-boot-only-after-subsequent-reboot

Comment: @Colin'tHart I actually did not, and it sounds like you arrived at the same thing I did, which was just removing `resolvconf` entirely. Newer Ubuntus do everything I need without it, so that ended up being a fine solution.