# /etc/resolv.conf not populated on boot, only after subsequent reboot

Tags: networking, resolv.conf, resolvconf

We have an Ubuntu Server 16.04.7 virtual machine running on top of Proxmox 6.3.

On reboot of the host, this machine comes up with an "empty" `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

If I subsequently reboot this virtual machine, `/etc/resolv.conf` gets populated as expected:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.100.10
nameserver 192.168.100.11
search domain.com
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` is as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
    address 192.168.100.189
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.100.0
    broadcast 192.168.100.255
    gateway 192.168.100.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.100.10 192.168.100.11
    dns-search domain.com
```

`resolvconf` is installed, and I can't find any meaningful differences between this installation and any of the many other virtual machines we have. The contents of `/etc/resolvconf` on this machine are identical to another working machine on the same node; we haven't edited the `resolv.conf.d` files.

We are also running `keepalived` on this node, with configuration as follows:

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface ens18
    virtual_router_id 188
    priority 150
    advert_int 1
    notify /script/to/start/and/stop/fetchmail
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.100.188
    }
}
```

where `/script/to/start/and/stop/fetchmail` is basically as it says: a script to start and stop fetchmail depending on whether or not this node is the master.

Where do I even begin to start looking to resolve (pun intentional!) this problem?

Comment: Just checking - have you edited your resolv.conf.d files?
Also - I assume this is an ubuntu server machine?

Comment: No DHCP. Yes, Ubuntu Server. resolv.conf.d unmodified versus another working machine on the same node.

Comment: I ended up removing the `resolvconf` package (and along with it the `ubuntu-minimal` metapackage) and creating a static `/etc/resolv.conf` file. We never upgrade our server OSes anyway -- we install a new and copy across the data so we have a rollback possibility when upgrading -- so the removal of the metapackage is a non-issue for us.